# EpicEditor: themes not found

Tags: javascript, epiceditor

I have a static directory that contains subdirectories to css/, js/, fonts/ and images/. After downloading EpicEditor, I placed epiceditor.min.js in the js/ directory, and had this line in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/epiceditor.min.js"></script>
```

but this gives an error:

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:6543/static/js/epiceditor.min.js/themes/base/epiceditor.css 404 (Not Found)
```

If I instead use a separate directory for EpicEditor:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/epiceditor/js/epiceditor.min.js"></script>
```

this is the error that I get:

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:6543/epiceditor/js/epiceditor.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I change the href to point towards the correct location? Or, where am I supposed to place the various files for EpicEditor?

Answer (score 0):

I realised what I had been doing wrong: the basePath option should have a filepath that leads to the themes for EpicEditor.